# Chrome Driver Selenium Download Location

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, download, path

I tried everything to change the default download path at Chrome and nothing works.

I'm using .Net Core 2.0 C#

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" Version="2.30.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" Version="0.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="2.33.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver" Version="15.15063.0" />

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", path);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(path, chromeOptions);
```

I've tried also the class with prefs and doesn't worked too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue when upgrading to chrome webdriver 2.30, in my case, default download directory was no more taken into account.
Try to upgrade it to (currently) latest 2.33, it was fixed between this two versions (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

This was my code sample:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Configuration.ResourcesPath);
```

Nuget package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver is up to date (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/)